# How to code for push notification in android using c#?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, push-notification

Im new to android app development, i need to code for app which has push notification facility, i need the idea to code for push notification which should be connected with mySQL DB... please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this for sending notification from server to the device using .net c# code

Ref.: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/434338/Android-GCM-Push-Notification

```
public class AndroidGCMPushNotification
{
    public AndroidGCMPushNotification()
    {
        //
        // TODO: Add constructor logic here
        //
    }
    public string SendNotification(string deviceId, string message)
    {
        string GoogleAppID = "google application id";        
        var SENDER_ID = "9999999999";
        var value = message;
        WebRequest tRequest;
        tRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send");
        tRequest.Method = "post";
        tRequest.ContentType = " application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8";
        tRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Authorization: key={0}", GoogleAppID));

        tRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Sender: id={0}", SENDER_ID));

        string postData = "collapse_key=score_update&time_to_live=108&
        delay_while_idle=1&data.message=" + value + "&data.time=" + 
        System.DateTime.Now.ToString() + "®istration_id=" + deviceId + "";
        Console.WriteLine(postData);
        Byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
        tRequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

        Stream dataStream = tRequest.GetRequestStream();
        dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        dataStream.Close();

        WebResponse tResponse = tRequest.GetResponse();

        dataStream = tResponse.GetResponseStream();

        StreamReader tReader = new StreamReader(dataStream);

        String sResponseFromServer = tReader.ReadToEnd();

        tReader.Close();
        dataStream.Close();
        tResponse.Close();
        return sResponseFromServer;
    }
}
```

Handling the message in the device

https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html

Answer (score 0):

A quick way to get started with this is to use Google Cloud Messaging.

https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html